# What's the meaning of "honour" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following is a passage from an article on The Hollywood Walk of Fame:

> Having a star on the Hollywood Walk of Fame is a huge **honor.** Specific requirements are laid out for those actors, musicians, directors, producers and others who earn a spot on the walk.

Does *honor* in this context mean: [an award, official title, etc. given to somebody as a reward for something that they have done?](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/honour)

Comment: In what would otherwise be a one-word answer:  *Yes* (that's what it means)

Comment: I like sense 2 for this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it's not technically *an award* in this sense.  The star itself is an award/honor, but that's not what this is referring to.

It's a sense of prestige, recognition, admiration, achievement, etc.

> That you *have chosen **to honor** me [recognize my work]* with this ***honor*** [award] is indeed truly an ***honor*** [truly a tremendous privilege/achievement] to me.

It's more like the first and third uses of *honor* above, but more specifically, it's the third since it's a noun.

It's somewhere between [1 and 2 here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/honor). And it's more like [3 here](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/honor%5B1%5D).

In [your source](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/honour), it's number 2.